# Drag & Drop 2 window synchronize in GTK

Tags: gtk

I have two windows: A & B. like this:

[image]

Window B just is a popup of window A.
So when I move Window A, I want Window B move, too. 
I try catch signal Drag and Drop from Window A to set position to Window B. But it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me? Or have any idea about type of B, it is window or dialog or popup?

Comment: The drag and drop signals are not for dragging the window around, they are for dropping stuff **into** the window. I think you want the allocation signals but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try `configure-event`, I think.

Comment: I'm sure you can hack this (`configure-event` does sound correct) but it really is a window management feature: As an example, if you create a modal transient GtkWindow in a GNOME environment, the modal window will follow the main window around as you expect.